# Using ImmutableSortedSet<T> for a thread safe cache

Tags: c#, caching, immutability, sortedset

I have a method that takes a `DateTime` and returns the date marking the end of that quarter. Because of some complexity involving business days and holiday calendars, I want to cache the result to speed up subsequent calls. I'm using a `SortedSet<DateTime>` to maintain a cache of data, and I use the `GetViewBetween` method in order to do cache lookups as follows:

```
private static SortedSet<DateTime> quarterEndCache = new SortedSet<DateTime>();

public static DateTime GetNextQuarterEndDate(DateTime date)
{
    var oneDayLater = date.AddDays(1.0);
    var fiveMonthsLater = date.AddMonths(5);
    var range = quarterEndCache.GetViewBetween(oneDayLater, fiveMonthsLater);
    if (range.Count > 0)
    {
        return range.Min;
    }

    // Perform expensive calc here
}
```

Now I want to make my cache threadsafe. Rather than use a lock everywhere which would incur a performance hit on every lookup, I'm exploring the new `ImmutableSortedSet<T>` collection which would allow me to avoid locks entirely. The problem is that `ImmutableSortedSet<T>` doesn't have the method `GetViewBetween`. Is there any way to get similar functionality from the `ImmutableSortedSet<T>`?

[EDIT]

Servy has convinced me just using a lock with a normal `SortedSet<T>` is the easiest solution. I'll leave the question open though just because I'm interested to know whether the `ImmutableSortedSet<T>` can handle this scenario efficiently.

Comment: The easiest option is probably going to just be to use a read/write lock around the set.  Making the set immutable doesn't just instantly remove all synchronization issues, as you're still mutating the variable holding the collection.

Comment: @Servy Exchanging the variable reference during an insert is atomic. The worse case scenario is that the expensive calc is performed again unnecessarily if the lookup occurs before the cache update, but the benefit is that we don't need to obtain a lock for every lookup; in the case of a single thread there is no lock-obtaining overhead, and in the case of multiple threads there is no lock contention.

Comment: But you also need to introduce memory barriers for the change to be observed.  And the cost of re-computing the expensive calculation is going to completely dwarf the costs of taking out an uncontested lock.  Uncontested locks are *very* cheap to acquire.

Comment: Note that `GetViewBetween` returns a *view* on the underlying SortedSet, not a totally new collection. Thus if you are iterating on `range` you cannot update `quarterEndCache` from another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the tip mike, I made sure to include any code using the range in the critical section.

Answer (score 3):

Let's divide the question into two parts:

1. *How to get a functionality similar to `GetViewBetween` with `ImmutableSortedSet<T>`?* I'd suggest using the `IndexOf` method. In the snippet below, I created an extension method `GetRangeBetween` which should do the job.
2. *How to implement lock-free, thread-safe updates with data immutable data structures?* Despite this is not the original question, there are some skeptical comments with respect to this issue. 
   The immutables framework implements a method for exactly that purpose: `System.Collections.Immutable.Update<T>(ref T location, Func<T, T> transformer) where T : class;` The method internally relies on atomic compare/exchange operations. If you want to do this by hand, you'll find an alternative implementation below which should behave the same like Immutable.Update.

So here is the code:

```
public static class ImmutableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRangeBetween<T>(
        this ImmutableSortedSet<T> set, T min, T max)
    {
        int i = set.IndexOf(min);
        if (i < 0) i = ~i;
        while (i < set.Count)
        {
            T x = set[i++];

            if (set.KeyComparer.Compare(x, min) >= 0 &&
                set.KeyComparer.Compare(x, max) <= 0)
            {
                yield return x;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void LockfreeUpdate<T>(ref T item, Func<T, T> fn)
        where T: class
    {
        T x, y;

        do
        {
            x = item;
            y = fn(x);

        } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref item, y, x) != x);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    private static volatile ImmutableSortedSet<DateTime> quarterEndCache =
        ImmutableSortedSet<DateTime>.Empty;
    private static volatile int counter; // test/verification purpose only

    public static DateTime GetNextQuarterEndDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var oneDayLater = date.AddDays(1.0);
        var fiveMonthsLater = date.AddMonths(5);
        var range = quarterEndCache.GetRangeBetween(oneDayLater, fiveMonthsLater);
        if (range.Any())
        {
            return range.First();
        }

        // Perform expensive calc here
        // -> Meaningless dummy computation for verification purpose only
        long x = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        DateTime test = DateTime.FromFileTime(x);
        ImmutableExtensions.LockfreeUpdate(
            ref quarterEndCache,
            c => c.Add(test));

        return test;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIt()
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable
            .Range(0, 100000)
            .Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => GetNextQuarterEndDate(DateTime.Now)))
            .ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        Assert.AreEqual(100000, counter);
    }
```

Comment: Seems the type you mentioned is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.update?view=netcore-3.1#definition